# Given two matrices A and B, compute the convolution mask sending A to B?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose

```
A = [0 0 0 0 1 
     0 0 0 1 1
     0 0 1 1 0
     0 1 1 0 0
     1 1 0 0 0]

B = [0 0 0 1/2 1
     0 0 1/2 1 1/2
     0 1/2 1 1/2 0
     1/2 1 1/2 0 0
     1 1/2 0 0 0
    ]
```

Find the 3x3 kernel K that Transforms A into B. Do so by hand. I believe I should be exploiting the structure of A, based on that I have for

```
K = [x1 x2 x3
     x4 x5 x6
     x7 x8 x9
     ]

x9,x3,x1,x7 = 0
```

But I am not sure how to solve the rest without brute force computations. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
You can easily see that $K = K^T$ by symmetry of both $A$ and $B$.
Now look at the $(1,4)$-Entry and at the $(4,1)$-Entry.
What does this force $K$ to look like? Can you complete $K$ from there?

Remember that you already found out that
$$K = \pmatrix{0&a&0\\a&b&c\\0&c&0}$$
Using this information you can write down the equations from three entries of $B$ (chosen such that the resulting three equations in $a,b,c$ are linearly independent) - $(1,4)$, $(4,1)$ and $(3,3)$ should do.
Then solve the resulting system for $a,b$ and $c$.

Comment: I'm sorry what exactly do you mean by symmetry? I can see that A is identity matrix with 1s along the lower diagonal, and B is also a scaled identity matrix with 1/2s along the upper and lower diagonal. But I am not sure how this helps me with K.

Comment: Ummm, none of these are identity matrices. But they are both symmetric ($A=A^T$ and $B=B^T$).

Comment: so why does it follow that $A = A^T$?

Comment: It doesn't follow from anything but the "value" of $A$. $A^T$ is the _transpose_ of $A$.

Comment: could you elaborate on "what does this force K to look like?"

Comment: @working Done. Does it help?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure why we know K is that form? Couldn't K be some other form and still be symmetric?

Comment: You forgot your own constraints on $K$. In your OP you wrote the corner elements are $0$, you named them $x_1, x_3, x_7, x_9$. Now that I look at it, you can't really conclude $x_3 = x_7 = 0$ from anywhere unless that's a given, but they must be equal so you would need one additional set of equations to find them.